# Determine the effect of a function by its type

Tags: haskell, type-theory, hindley-milner

One of the interesting properties of Haskell's type system (*) is that sometimes you can tell *exactly* what the function does based only on its type signature (assuming there's no `unsafe IO` dark magic invloved).

For example, any function with the type signature `a -> a` must be the identity function, and any function of type `(a,b) -> a` is equivalent to `fst`. In some cases you cannot determine the function completely: there is an infinite number of different possible functions of type `a -> Int`, but all of them are constant - they all ignore the first parameter.

I find this property fascinating, but I suspect it only applies to "trivial" functions such as `id` and `const`. Am I correct?

Also, my reasoning here is based only on intuition - for example, in `a -> a`, we "know nothing" about `a` (as opposed to constrained functions like `Num a => a -> a`) so "can't do anything" with it other than to return in unchanged. Is there a formal way to deal with these kind of deductions?

<sub>* I know Haskell's type system is based on the *Hindley–Milner type system*, but I'm not familiar with it enough to assume anything about it</sub>

Comment: I couldn't think of an appropriate title and I'm not content with the current one - suggestions and/or edits are welcome. Thanks!

Comment: Philip Wadler's paper "Theorems for free!" deals with this topic. I don't understand it well enough to write an answer though.

Comment: @delnan Thanks! Here's a [link](http://ttic.uchicago.edu/~dreyer/course/papers/wadler.pdf) for future readers. It does seem to require a basic background in type theory.

Comment: It may not be a terribly useful function, but `\x -> undefined` can be given the type signature `a -> a`.

Comment: @NeilForrester So can `undefined`, and indeed program transformations based on parametricity are unsound in the presence of a function like `seq`. See also *Free Theorems in the Presence of *seq*" [\[PDF\]](https://github.com/aistrate/Articles/raw/master/Haskell/Free%20Theorems%20in%20the%20Presence%20of%20seq%20(Johann%2C%20Voigtlaender).pdf)

Comment: @NeilForrester - you're right. However its true type AFAIK is `a -> ⊥`

Comment: @Benesh ⊥ is not a type. ⊥ is an inhabitant of all types. Its true type is `forall a. a -> a`.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The concept you are referring to is known as [parametricity](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Parametricity). Universal quantification over types gives parametric polymorphism and a "uniformity" property that is intuitively this notion that "we don't know anything about" `a` in `forall a. a -> a` and so "can't do anything" with it other than return it unchanged. What the uniformity property says is that a type `f :: [a] -> [a]` does not depend on the type of `a`, or, more precisely, depends *uniformly* on it: that anything one "does" to the `[a]` must be "doable" for *all* choices of `a`. Wadler uses this to show that mapping the values in the list and then permuting the list is equivalent to permuting first and mapping after.

The formal way to deal with these intuitions is given in, e.g.,
Philip Wadler's *[Theorems for Free](http://ttic.uchicago.edu/~dreyer/course/papers/wadler.pdf)* and involves an isomorphism between types and relations (in fact the category **PER** of partial equivalence relations (p.e.r.'s)) which shows that this uniformity is a universal property in the category.

One interesting result of parametricity is that you can go "both ways": from a type to theorems about that type, and from a type to inhabitants of that type. Wadler's free theorems are an example of the former and [Djinn](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/djinn), a theorem prover (inhabitants of a type are "proofs" of the type's "theorem"), is an example of the latter.